# I think my code is good but it stops after cin a and dont go further?

Tags: c++

So here is the code.
Please tell me what is wrong in this code and why does this stop after taking cin>>a;

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int x;
 int y;

int main(){
cout<<"What do you want to do:-"<<endl<<"add"<<endl<<"sub"<<endl<<"mul"<<endl<<"div"<<endl;
string a;
cin >> a;

if('a' =='add')
{
    cout<<"working"<<endl;//this was used to check whether was working or not but it didn't
    cin>>x;
    cin>>y;
    cout<< x+y <<endl;
}
if('a' =='sub')
    {
        cout<<"working"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        cin>>y;
        cout<< x-y <<endl;
    }
if('a' =='mul')
    {
        cout<<"working"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        cin>>y;
        cout<< x*y <<endl;
    }
if('a' =='div')
    {
        cout<<"working"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        cin>>y;
        cout<< x/y <<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

So it perfectly builds.I am using eclipse ide.
Thank you

Comment: What was your input? Try to debug your program.

Comment: *It perfectly builds* - It should not. You should get at least a warnings here `if('a' =='add')`: `'add'` is incorrect: simple quotes are for a single character. **Warnings are not to be ignored** (unless you fully understand what they mean and why they are harmless in a special use case)

Comment: People shouldn't be downvoting a question without commenting on why they are downvoting it.   So many more downvotes than comments or close votes says bad things about the community.

Comment: @SergeBallesta is right, it does not perfectly build with g++, neither with clang++. You get an error: `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
 if('a' =='add')`

Answer (score 2):

You code exits because all of these `if` statements are wrong. You compare a character `a` with a multi character constant `div` for example. What you really want to do is compare `strings`. More precisely the string stored in the variable `a` and a `string` constant.

The following should work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x;
int y;

int main(){
    cout<<"What do you want to do:-"<<endl<<"add"<<endl<<"sub"<<endl<<"mul"<<endl<<"div"<<endl;
    string a;
    cin >> a;

    if(a =="add")
    {
        cout<<"working"<<endl;//this was used to check whether was working or not but it didn't
        cin>>x;
        cin>>y;
        cout<< x+y <<endl;
    }
    if(a =="sub")
    {
        cout<<"working"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        cin>>y;
        cout<< x-y <<endl;
    }
    if(a =="mul")
    {
        cout<<"working"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        cin>>y;
        cout<< x*y <<endl;
    }
    if(a =="div")
    {
        cout<<"working"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        cin>>y;
        cout<< x/y <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You see:

`a` is accessed by dropping ' and a `string` constant needs " " instead of ' '.

I hope this helps!
Greetings

Comment: You're for the include for STD::string

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `strcmp` function  present in `string.h` header to compare strings in the `if` statement.

```
if(strcmp(a, "add") == 0) {
  // Addition code here...
}
```

Comment: Feel free to add a basic explanation to why strcmp would be the better alternative. Also worth pointing out why it does not work for him.

Comment: No need to use `strcmp` to check `std::string` equality just use the equality operator